# WinForms RotateFlipType equivalent in WPF using VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I'm converting an app from WinForms to WPF in VB and run in to the following error. In the original WinForms application, there's a line of code that controls the rotation of an image. Here it is:

```
bmpmetband.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY)
```

Now when I use this code in my WPF version, it has a red line under it. I can't find anywhere on the internet how to fix this or what the WPF equivalent of RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY is.
Can someone here help me?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914140/wpf-how-to-rotate-a-bitmapsource-by-any-angle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, equivalent is available in WPF, kindly look into RenderTransform

```
<Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
```